# BeagleBone kernel problem: waiting for root device

Tags: boot, beagleboard

I've got a BeagleBone Black which was initially built with (I believe) one of Robert C. Nelson's SD-to-MMC flashers.  This installed kernel version 3.8.13-bone28, which works fine.

I need to install kernel 4.4.12 that I built myself, using the kernel sources and build_kernel.sh script from https://github.com/RobertCNelson/bb-kernel .

I'm installing the new zImage in /boot/uboot/, the new dtbs files under /boot/uboot/dtbs/, the new modules in /lib/modules/4.4.12bf-bone11/, and the new firmware in /lib/firmware/ .

The new kernel gets partway through its boot, but it hangs forever waiting for root device UUID=... .

I tried doing

```
update-initramfs -k 4.4.12bf-bone11 -c
```

but it didn't help.

I tried removing 'rootwait' from the mmcrootfstype configuration in uEnv.txt, but that only made things worse.

I suspect the problem may have to do with a gpio line that may or may not accurately indicate that the onboard eMMC "disk" is ready. (But if so, that's weird, because as I mentioned, the prebuilt 3.8.13 boots just fine.)

Can anyone suggest what step I might have missed?  I can see that lots of people have had similar problems, but not close enough to mine that their solutions helped.

P.S. I know that my new 4.4.12 kernel is nominally good, because I successfully integrated it with a stock Debian install on the same BeagleBone.  But my colleagues on this project insist on Ubuntu.

P.P.S. I wouldn't need to build my own kernel if I could figure out how to compile a certain module against the 3.8.13 kernel I already have. But compiling a module always seems to require a full kernel build directory to build against.

P.P.P.S. I wouldn't need to compile my own module if Linux would pick up the new asix.ko module from  http://www.asix.com.tw/download.php?sub=driverdetail&PItemID=105 .  But none of the stock Linux kernel builds seem to have it yet.

Comment: You could get the full kernel sources for the precompiled ubuntu kernel by installing the matching linux-headers and linux-source packages, generally the linux-headers should be sufficient to compile a kernel module with DKMS the other advantage of making use of DKMS of course would also be the fact that apt can then automatically rebuild the module when future kernel versions are released in the repository. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS

Comment: @MttJocy `apt-get install linux-headers` says "Package linux-headers is a virtual package provided by" followed by a list of choices which does not obviously include my 3.8.13.  How do I know which one to pick?